# При наведении на одно изображение изменять css свойство другого

Tags: css

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на одно изображение изменялось css свойство другого?
Вот так не работает

```
.site_1:hover > .site_name_1 {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/i11.png" width="32" height="37" class="site_1" id="21" title="Горная" onclick="edim('0', '1', '0', '0', '12.5')"/>
</a>  
...  
<div class="site_name_1">Горная</div>
```

Comment: Покажите структуру HTML

Comment: Только через JS.

Comment: А как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы опять уничтожили весь HTML. Попробуйте освоится с разметкой.

Comment: Хорошо! А как можно сделать на JS?

Comment: только css3 http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6RaEQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте CSS-селектор **~** (siblings)- соседи.

---

```
.site_1:hover ~ .site_name_1
```

---

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/azedA/2/

Answer (score 3):

В head вставьте:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script><!-- подключаем JQuery, если подключено ранее не вставлять эти строчки -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function chgcss(imgid) {
$(imgid).css('css-свойство', 'значение');
}
</script>
```

Событие наведения на картинку:

```
<img src="ваша_картинка_которую_менять.png" id="pic1">
<img src="ваша_картинка_на_которую_наводить.png" onmouseover="chgcss('pic1')">
```